# GeoServer admin GUI with proxy base URL setting

Tags: geoserver

I have GeoServer running as a war file behind a Tomcat server, and I use the proxyBaseUrl setting in my GeoServer global.xml which was working fine in v2.18.2. However I tried upgrading to v2.21.5, and I cannot log on to the WebUI as admin anymore, because it keeps redirecting to my proxy.
I have tried to change the WebUI Mode setting in the global.xml settings to '**do not redirect**' but it doesn't change anything.
Is there a way to fix that behaviour ?

Comment: what do you mean by "keeps redirecting"? what did you set your proxy to and what is your actual set up?

Comment: My proxy is set to redirect my geoserver requests to the appropriate server where the actual geoserver is installed. I use proxyBaseUrl global setting to have my proxy address referenced in my GetCapabilities, however i would like to stick to my local geoserver address when logging on to the webUI but it redirects to my proxy server address when I log on and I get weird html pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, if you need to set a proxyBaseUrl to appear in the Geoserver GetCapabilities responses, but you don't want the web UI to redirect to the proxy url at log on, the proxyBaseUrl shall be set in the workspace settings (https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/data/webadmin/workspaces.html#workspace-settings) not in the global settings (https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have Geoserver 2.20.3. To set it behind "proxy + TLS" I have added
/opt/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml
and edited (uncommented block addCustomizer)
/opt/geoserver/etc/jetty.xml
My /opt/geoserver/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml:

```
<!-- File: web-app/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml -->
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <!-- Application name is 'geoserver' --> 
  <Set name="contextPath">/rmdl/plk/geoservermaster/geoserver</Set> 
</Configure>
```

My /opt/geoserver/etc/jetty.xml:

```
    <!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
    <Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
        <Call name="addBean">
          <Arg>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler">
                  <Arg name="name"><Property name="jetty.scheduler.name"/></Arg>
                  <Arg name="daemon" type="boolean"><Property name="jetty.scheduler.daemon" default="false" /></Arg>
                  <Arg name="threads" type="int"><Property name="jetty.scheduler.threads" default="-1" /></Arg>
              </New>
          </Arg>
        </Call>
        <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
            <Set name="secureScheme"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.secureScheme" default="https" /></Set>
            <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.securePort" deprecated="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" /></Set>
            <Set name="outputBufferSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.outputBufferSize" deprecated="jetty.output.buffer.size" default="32768" /></Set>
            <Set name="outputAggregationSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.outputAggregationSize" deprecated="jetty.output.aggregation.size" default="8192" /></Set>
            <Set name="requestHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize" deprecated="jetty.request.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
            <Set name="responseHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.responseHeaderSize" deprecated="jetty.response.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
            <Set name="sendServerVersion"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.sendServerVersion" deprecated="jetty.send.server.version" default="true" /></Set>
            <Set name="sendDateHeader"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.sendDateHeader" deprecated="jetty.send.date.header" default="false" /></Set>
            <Set name="headerCacheSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.headerCacheSize" default="1024" /></Set>
            <Set name="delayDispatchUntilContent"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.delayDispatchUntilContent" deprecated="jetty.delayDispatchUntilContent" default="true"/></Set>
            <Set name="maxErrorDispatches"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.maxErrorDispatches" default="10"/></Set>
            <Set name="blockingTimeout"><Property deprecated="jetty.httpConfig.blockingTimeout" name="jetty.httpConfig.blockingTimeout.DEPRECATED" default="-1"/></Set>
            <Set name="persistentConnectionsEnabled"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.persistentConnectionsEnabled" default="true"/></Set>
            <Set name="requestCookieCompliance"><Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.CookieCompliance" name="valueOf"><Arg><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.requestCookieCompliance" deprecated="jetty.httpConfig.cookieCompliance" default="RFC6265"/></Arg></Call></Set>
            <Set name="responseCookieCompliance"><Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.CookieCompliance" name="valueOf"><Arg><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.responseCookieCompliance" default="RFC6265"/></Arg></Call></Set>
            <Set name="multiPartFormDataCompliance"><Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.MultiPartFormDataCompliance" name="valueOf"><Arg><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.multiPartFormDataCompliance" default="RFC7578"/></Arg></Call></Set>
            <Set name="relativeRedirectAllowed"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.relativeRedirectAllowed" default="false"/></Set>
            <Call name="addCustomizer">
                <Arg><New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer"/></Arg>
            </Call>
        </New>
        <Call name="setAttribute">
          <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize</Arg>
          <Arg>500000</Arg>
        </Call>
        <Call name="setAttribute">
          <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormKeys</Arg>
          <Arg>2000</Arg>
        </Call>
        <Set name="handler">
            <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
                <Set name="handlers">
                    <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
                        <Item>
                            <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
                        </Item>
                    </Array>
                </Set>
            </New>
        </Set>
        <Set name="stopAtShutdown"><Property name="jetty.server.stopAtShutdown" default="true"/></Set>
        <Set name="stopTimeout"><Property name="jetty.server.stopTimeout" default="5000"/></Set>
        <Set name="dumpAfterStart"><Property name="jetty.server.dumpAfterStart" deprecated="jetty.dump.start" default="false"/></Set>
        <Set name="dumpBeforeStop"><Property name="jetty.server.dumpBeforeStop" deprecated="jetty.dump.stop" default="false"/></Set>
    </Configure>
```

See https://serverfault.com/questions/618172/https-reverse-proxy-on-http-jetty

Comment: I'm not using Jetty but Tomcat to run Geoserver