# How to properly publish GeoServer layers

Tags: geoserver, nginx

I developed a map visor for my company and the layers are published through GeoServer. I've used Tomcat for deploying GeoServer and Nginx as a reverse proxy (that I also use for Gunicorn+Django for the main web).

Right now GeoServer is accessible through the web at gs.mydomain.com/geoserver. However gs.mydomain.com points to the default Nginx welcome page and if you try to login in geoserver through gs.mydomain.com/geoserver, it redirects to http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/j_spring_security_check and I get a connection error. Layers are still accessible from my main web and WMS is working fine.

However, I doubt that I'm following the correct approach to make WMS accessible through the web. I'm the only programmer in my company and I started coding last year, so I feel a bit lost sometimes, specially configuring servers.

I guess that what I'm looking for is that gs.mydomain.com points directly to GeoServer and to be able to login and manage it from a computer different than my server.

Here is my geoserver.conf in nginx configuration:

```
server {
        server_name gs.mydomain.es;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/tomcat-error.log;

        location /geoserver/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/;
                proxy_set_header Host gs.mydomain.es;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

        # Otras configuraciones aquí

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/gs.mydomain.es/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/gs.mydomain.es/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = gs.mydomain.es) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name gs.mydomain.es;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/471650/geoserver-admin-gui-with-proxy-base-url-setting help?